# How to start and use Elsevier cas-sc-template

Tags: miktex, texworks, els-cas

years ago, i wrote my thesis with TeXnicCenter which was no big deal for me. My sister now has to publish her MD testis and she has to use elsevir cas-sc-template. I sad to help her, but i try to get it started for hours now and i dont get it to run.

I installed MiKTeX and TeXworks but i dont get the template to run.
Can somebody tell me which environment to use, how to add elsevir tex sources.

Thank you!

Comment: I currently got stuck with the error:

"File ended while scanning use of \next."

Comment: last view console output lines are:

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ./cas-sc-template.tex
                         
?

I also dont unserstand why it says "pdftex" as i am using "pdfLaTeX" in TeXworks

Comment: pdftex is the name of the driver and this is fine. Beside this: one can't help you if you don't show the code. Also be aware that you can't use the template unchanged, you have to fill the placeholders first.

Comment: And if you have the option, use `elsarticle` instead.  It works

Comment: it is till the default cas-sc-template.tex file from the bundle.

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates